# sharpGL in C# wpf cannot generate buffers

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

This simple code gives system exception and I cannot trace it since I cannot make output to console in wpf.

```
OpenGL gl = new OpenGL();
// OpenGL gl = openGLControl.OpenGL; doesnt change result
uint[] buf = new uint[1];
buf.Initialize();
gl.GenBuffers(1, buf); //commenting this line out, makes the exception vanish
```

What could cause `GenBuffers` method to raise the system exception in SharpGL.dll?

Using last version of sharpGL and .Net 4.0 targeted VS2012.

Should I install opengl for C++ and use a wrapper of that in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep for that: try setting the RenderContextType to DIBSection, to disable hardware acceleration and see if it still throws the exception.

```
        uint[] buf = new uint[1];
        buf.Initialize();

        var cn = new OpenGLControl();
        cn.RenderContextType = RenderContextType.DIBSection;
        cn.OpenGL.GenBuffers(1, buf);
```

Comment: Im newbie about gl, thank you for your effort but this gives same error (system exception in SharpGL.dll)